# Help with second-order linear ODE | $y''(t) + a y'(t) + b y(t) = c$ | Modeling Driven damped harmonic ocsilator with constant force

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I got kicked from physics stackoverflow for too mathematical question.

I'm trying to solve the following equation:

$y''(t) + a y'(t) + b y(t) = c$

That basically represents a forced damped harmonic oscillator with constant force applied.

The wolforamalpha gave me this solution:

$ y(t) = c_1 e^{\frac{1}{2} t \left(-\sqrt{a^2-4 b}-a\right)}+c_2
e^{\frac{1}{2} t \left(\sqrt{a^2-4 b}-a\right)}+\frac{c}{b} $

However, I have an under-damped oscilator, that means that: $a^2<4b$

I know that I need to apply an Euler formula (?): $e^{i x} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x)$ to solve this mess. My math knowledge ends here.

I am not sure how to proceed next.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

note that $i\sqrt{k}=\sqrt{-k}$

you say that $\sqrt{\frac14a^2-b}=i\sqrt{b-\frac14a^2}$ so:
 $$y(t) = c_1 e^{ t \left(-\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}a^2- b}-\frac{1}{2}a\right)}+c_2
e^{ t \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}a^2- b}-\frac{1}{2}a\right)}+\frac{c}{b}=c_1 e^{  -it\sqrt{b-\frac14a^2}-t\frac12a}+c_2
e^{ it\sqrt{b-\frac{1}{4}a^2}-t\frac{1}{2}a}+\frac{c}{b}=c_1 \frac{e^{  -it\sqrt{b-\frac14a^2}}}{e^{t\frac12a}}+c_2\frac{
e^{ it\sqrt{b-\frac{1}{4}a^2}}}{e^{t\frac{1}{2}a}}+\frac{c}{b}$$

now you can use $e^{i x} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x), x=\pm t\sqrt{b-\frac{1}{4}a^2}$ (- for the first and + for the second)

Comment: how can I get y'(0) after that?

Comment: take the derivative of $y(t)$, you can take the derivative of $c_1 e^{\frac{1}{2} t \left(-\sqrt{a^2-4 b}-a\right)}+c_2 e^{\frac{1}{2} t \left(\sqrt{a^2-4 b}-a\right)}+\frac{c}{b}$, you don't need to take the derivative after simplifying. You will get $c_1\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{a^2-4 b}-a\right) e^{\frac{1}{2} t \left(-\sqrt{a^2-4 b}-a\right)}+c_2 \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{a^2-4 b}-a\right)e^{\frac{1}{2} t \left(\sqrt{a^2-4 b}-a\right)}$. Put $t=0$ to get $c_1\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{a^2-4 b}-a\right)+c_2\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{a^2-4 b}-a\right)$with initial knowledge you can find $y'(0)$